# pipline implementation with PCA sklearn and TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn

it gives another error.

The first argument to `Layer.call` must always be passed.

I cannot solve the problem. input_dim cannot be set as a constant. PCA and SelectKBest will cut down on the amount of input.

And if you can help with the output of the results from the pipeline, I will be very grateful

attach a link to the data: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlHgQsqCKEIPiIxzdyWE0BfBHNocTQ?e=cxuSuo

```
def modelReg(inpt, opt = 'adam', kInitializer = 'glorot_uniform', dropout = 0.05):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu', input_dim = inpt, kernel_initializer=kInitializer))
    model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kInitializer))
    model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kInitializer))
    model.add(layers.Dropout(dropout))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer=kInitializer))
    model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer=opt, metrics=["mse", "mae"])
    return model

features = []
features.append(('pca', PCA(n_components=10)))
features.append(('select_best', SelectKBest(k=10)))
feature_union = FeatureUnion(features)

regressor = KerasRegressor(build_fn = modelReg(inpt), epochs = 3, batch_size = 500, verbose = 1)

estimators = []
estimators.append(('standardize', StandardScaler()))
estimators.append(('feature_union', feature_union))
estimators.append(('regressor' regressor))
model = Pipeline(estimators)

model.fit(allData.drop(['VancouverH'], axis = 1), allData['VancouverH'])
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in KerasRegressor with a function to pass arguments to the model function, they are written to the KerasRegressor arguments.

```
kearsEstimator = ('kR', KerasRegressor(createModel, inpt = trainDataX.shape[1], 
                                                 epochs = 5, batch_size = 180, verbose = 1))
```

like this, not like this:

```
kearsEstimator = ('kR', KerasRegressor(createModel(inpt), 
                                                 epochs = 5, batch_size = 180, verbose = 1))
```

well, and transferred the pipeline to the Grid. And the names of the parameters for the grid are written with the prefix.

```
estimators = []
estimators.append((kearsEstimator))
param_grid = { 
    'kR__optimizer':['adam'] #'RMSprop', 'Adam', 'Adamax', 'sgd'
}
grid = GridSearchCV(Pipeline(estimators), param_grid, cv = 5)
grid.fit(trainDataX, trainDataY)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. You may also accept your own answer.

Comment: I've only been writing code for a month)) I'm a beginner. I myself still do not understand well. But I'm full of ambition)) and I only learn English ((Hard. and they do not take a job (and I can do everything. I study quickly, but we will not give up)) I will learn the language and I will help people here)